# React Native Flatlist keyExtractor Clarification

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm a bit new to React Native and am trying to grasp a few concepts at a time but am stuck on a flatlist that has data without a true unique id. Best I could do is an index, but everyone says not to use an index.

At the moment this is my flatlist:

```
<FlatList
        data={property.Shipment.Comments}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
          <View style={styles.flatview}>
            <Text style={styles.ac}>{item.ActivityCode}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.s}>{item.StatusComment}</Text>
          </View>
          }
      />
```

This is after pulling my data from this array:

```
"Comments":[
               {
                  "ActivityCode":null,
                  "StatusComment":"10/05/2018 08:20 AM Pickup Request Received.",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-05T08:20:00",
                  "Status":null,
                  "Reason":null
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"PU",
                  "StatusComment":"10/05/2018 10:09 AM Shipment was picked up",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-05T10:09:00",
                  "Status":null,
                  "Reason":null
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"ARQ",
                  "StatusComment":"10/05/2018 05:14 PM Appointment Pending",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-05T17:14:00",
                  "Status":null,
                  "Reason":null
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"CLO",
                  "StatusComment":"10/05/2018 08:22 PM Trailer Closed - ready for dispatch",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-05T20:22:00",
                  "Status":null,
                  "Reason":null
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"DSP",
                  "StatusComment":"10/06/2018 08:45 AM Trailer dispatched from BOLINGBROOK, IL to DENVER, CO.",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-06T08:45:00",
                  "Status":"L1",
                  "Reason":"NS"
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"ARV",
                  "StatusComment":"10/08/2018 02:00 PM Trailer arrived at terminal in DENVER, CO",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-08T14:00:00",
                  "Status":"O1",
                  "Reason":"NS"
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"UNL",
                  "StatusComment":"10/09/2018 09:00 AM Trailer unloaded at terminal in DENVER, CO",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-09T09:00:00",
                  "Status":null,
                  "Reason":null
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"OFD",
                  "StatusComment":"10/12/2018 06:00 AM Shipment out for delivery",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-12T06:00:00",
                  "Status":"OD",
                  "Reason":"NS"
               },
               {
                  "ActivityCode":"DEL",
                  "StatusComment":"10/12/2018 12:00 PM Shipment delivered to consignee",
                  "StatusDateTime":"2018-10-12T12:00:00",
                  "Status":"D1",
                  "Reason":"NS"
               }
            ],
```

Is there an appropriate way of using the keyExtractor with the above data? In my case, I'm not sure how important it is as the list is view only. In fact this test data I'm working with is based on an older project of mine where there was no data manipulation at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you have access to the backend why not to add id field , if not personally i will go with statusComment as id in the key extractor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Let's understand what is KEY in react.
React uses key to uniquely identify components and while re-rendering, react uses these key to understand what part of UI should be updated. Thus Keys are useful when you are working with dynamically created components or when your lists are altered by the users. In flatlist, KEYEXTRACTOR defines react key only.

As per my understanding, If you have readonly data and not creating dynamic components, keys are not very useful hence you can use index as key.

PS - Answer to this part "am stuck on a flatlist that has data without a true unique id". We can always create unique IDs in frontend and assign them as key, if required. (In case, API data / response doesn't have any unique key.

Answer (score 1):

All data sets for a FlatList should have a unique key to identify each item. This is so the FlatList can efficiently use virtualization for your rows as you scroll.

In your case, the easiest way to get a key is to generate one when you get your data from the API. You can use a package like [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) to generate unique ids.

An example might look like this:

```js
import shortid from 'shortid'

// Get API data
const data = await myAPICall();

const comments = data.map(a => ({
  ...a,
  id: shortid.generate()
}))

this.setState({
  comments
})
```